# Trim whitespace from x.org copy/paste buffer

Tags: clipboard

I am frequently copying and pasting text from a browser (hundreds of times per day), but sometimes the text I select has leading or trailing whitespace. Sometimes it seems that this whitespace is inserted automatically, no matter how accurately I select the text with my mouse. Is it possible to trim any leading or trailing whitespace automatically when I issue ctrl+c to X.org? Intermediate whitespace should be left intact. If it helps, I'm using fluxbox as my window manager, and glipper as my clipboard manager. OS is Debian Jessie.

Thanks!